# Create union of two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, union

I have two dataframes with identical columns. However the 'labels' column can have different labels. All labels are comma seperated strings. I want to make a union on the labels in order to go from this:

df1:

```
    id1   id2 labels language
0   1     1   1      en
1   2     3          en
2   3     4   4      en
3   4     5          en
4   5     6          en
```

df2:

```
    id1   id2 labels language
0   1     1   1,2    en
1   2     3          en
2   3     4   5,7    en
3   4     5          en
4   5     6   3      en
```

to this:

```
    id1   id2 labels language
0   1     1   1,2    en
1   2     3          en
2   3     4   4,5,7  en
3   4     5          en
4   5     6   3      en
```

I've tried this:

```
df1['labels'] = df1['labels'].apply(lambda x: set(str(x).split(',')))
df2['labels'] = df2['labels'].apply(lambda x: set(str(x).split(',')))
result = df1.merge(df2, on=['article_id', 'line_number', 'language'], how='outer')

result['labels'] = result[['labels_x', 'labels_y']].apply(lambda x: list(set.union(*x)) if None not in x else set(), axis=1)
result['labels'] = result['labels'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))
result = result.drop(['labels_x', 'techniques_y'], axis=1)
```

but I get a wierd df with odd commas in some places, e.g the `,3`.:

```
    id1   id2 labels language
0   1     1   1,2    en
1   2     3          en
2   3     4   4,5,7  en
3   4     5          en
4   5     6   ,3     en
```

How can I properly fix the commas? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution with [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) :

```
out = (
        df1.merge(df2, on=["id1", "id2", "language"])
            .assign(labels= lambda x: x.filter(like="label")
                                       .stack().str.split(",")
                                       .explode().drop_duplicates()
                                       .groupby(level=0).agg(",".join))
            .drop(columns=["labels_x", "labels_y"])
             [df1.columns]
      )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  id1 id2 labels language
0   1   1    1,2       en
1   2   3    NaN       en
2   3   4  4,5,7       en
3   4   5    NaN       en
4   5   6      3       en
```